# Problem Solving with Linear Equations... If she earns a total of $74, how many lemonades does she sell?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, word-problem

Theresa sells lemonade for 1 USD, juice for 1.50 USD,and coffee for 2 USD. The number of coffees she sells is twice the number of lemonades she sells, and 4 more than the number of juices she sells. If she earns a total of 74 USD, how many lemonades does she sell?

I know the answer is 10 lemonades but how could that answer be true? I have tried multiple ways to form an equation but I cannot seem to find the correct one. I don't know if I should make an equation. Ex, the coffee=2x. Juice= 1.50+(x+4). Lemonade=x. If someone just could translate the word problems into an equation, that would be more than just enough of a help!

From the help I received (The other comments solved for Lemonade and for Juice), so I tried to solve for coffee and then substitute the result for coffee in the first equation. Equation 1: 1*L+1.5*J+2*C=74. And we know that C= 2*L so it would mean L= C/2. And we also know C=J+4 so it would mean J= C-4. We substitute C/2 for lemonade and C-4 for Juice. And we get: (C/2)+2C+1.5(C-4)=74. So we get: (2C*2)+C/2 + 1.5(C-4)=74 into 4C+C/2 + 1.5(C-4)=74. We simplify (5C) numerator and (2) denominator by 2 and get 2.5C+1.5C-6=74 and collect like terms. 4C-6=74 (we add 6 to both sides.) 4c=80 (Divide both sides by 4.) C=20. So finally we can (20/2) + 2*(20) + 1.5 (20-4)=74. Lemonade= 10. Coffee= 20. Juice= 16

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: Finally I got something correct!

Answer (score 1):

The most challenging part of word problems is the translation into equations. That is the part you need to learn. This takes time and practice, and reading and re-reading word problems many times. You have to learn what phrases mean as equations.

Phrases like "thing1 is twice as big as thing2" mean that if thing2 is times by 2 we would get thing1, we would write $$T1=2\cdot T2$$ Here's another "there are 4 more apples than pears", as an equation $$A=4+P$$

After reading the entire word problem, I see that Theresa is trying to sell three things and has made some money. I see she is trying to sell lemonade, juice, and coffee. We see she made \$74. Does it make sense this translates to an equation? $$1\cdot L+1.5\cdot J+2\cdot C = 74$$

Now the more tricky parts, "coffees is twice the number of lemonades", do you see this as $$C = 2\cdot L$$ Now we translate "coffees is 4 more than the number of juices". Do you see the $$C = 4+J$$

Sometimes it helps to rephrase things in your own words. "I have 4 more apples than pears", "so if I add 4 to the number of pears I have, I have the amount off apples I have", $A=4+P$. This takes practice. Notice, I don't attempt to translate everything at once, I think about each phrase one at a time.

This is now the easy part, since we have translated all the words into equations, I no longer have to think about the words. I can simply focus on how to do algebra. Can you solve it from here amd find the number of lemonades that were sold? $$1\cdot L+1.5\cdot J+2\cdot C = 74$$ $$C = 2\cdot L$$ $$C = 4+J$$

Comment: Suggestion: Any variable introduced in solving the problem should be explicitly defined. (E.g., Let $C$ be the number of coffees sold.)

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me!

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be the number of coffee she sells; $j$ be the number of juices she sells; and $l$ be the number of lemonade she sells.
From this problem we can see three equations based on one statement concerning the relationships between them:

1. The number of coffees she sells is twice the number of lemonades she sells, and 4 more than the number of juices she sells.
   $$c=2l,\;\;\;\;c=j+4.$$
   Since the total is 74, we can write the following:
   $l+1.5j+2c = 74.$
   We can then substitute for $c$, since we know the number of cups of coffee in relation to the number of cups  juice she sells.
   Therefore, we have the following:
   $l+1.5j+2(j+4) = 74.$
   The next step is to distribute, $l+1.5j+2j+8=74.$
   Now we have two variables that is unknown to us. Let's read the statement again and see what we can find:

> The number of coffees she sells is twice the number of lemonades she sells, and 4 more than the number of juices she sells.

This means that $2l$ is the same as $j+4$.
But we do not want $2l$, we want to find $l$. Again, since $j+4$ is the same thing as $2l$, we can divide $j+4$ by $2$. Once we do that, we can solve the equation.
$\frac{j+4}{2}+1.5j+2j+8=74.$
Now we can multiply everything by 2 since that is the common denominator.
$j+4+3j+4j+16=148.$
Then, combine like terms.
$8j+20=148,\;\;$
$8j+20-20=148-20,\;\;$
$8j=128,\;\;$
$\frac{8j}{8}=\frac{128}{8},\;\;$
$j=16.$
Remember that $j$ is the juice variable. Once we solved for j, we can find $l$.
$l+1.5j+2j+8=74.$
This time, we will substitute 16 for $j$ and solve for $l$.
$l+1.5(16)+2(16)+8=74,\;\;$
$l+24+32+8=74,\;\;$
$l+64=74,\;\;$
$l+64-64=74-64,\;\;$
$l=10.$
Therefore, she sold 10 cups of lemonade.

Comment: Thank you so much! I truly appreciate your help. I wonder if there would be a way to focus on finding the number of coffees instead of number of juice? We don't have more information about the juice than the lemonade, so would there be a way to focus on making an equation with one unknown (being the lemonade)?

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely possible. The answer to your question is that you should focus on the relationship, and based on the relationship between them, you can set equations in any ways you want.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $l$ be the number of lemonades which Theresa sells; let $j$ be the number of juices she sells; let $c$ be the number of coffees she sells.  We were told that each lemonade sells for $\$1$, that each juice sells for $\$1.50$, and that each coffee sells for $\$2$.  We were also told that her total sales were $\$74$.  Hence,
$$l + 1.5j + 2c = 74 \tag{1}$$
In addition, we were told that the number of coffees Theresa sold is twice the number of lemonades that she sold, so
$$c = 2l$$
and that the number of coffees she solds was four more than the number of juices she sold, so
$$c = j + 4$$
Hence,
$$j = c - 4 = 2l - 4$$
If we substitute $2l$ for $c$ and $2l - 4$ for $j$ in equation $1$, we obtain
$$l + 1.5(2l - 4) + 2(2l) = 74 \tag{2}$$
Solving equation $2$ for $l$ will give you the number of lemonades she sells.

You can check your work in the following way.  After you determine $l$, use the equations $c = 2l$ and $j = 2l - 4$ to find, respectively, the number of coffees and juices that Theresa sold.  Substitute your values for $l$, $j$, and $c$ into the expression $l + 1.5j + 2c$.  If you solved the problem correctly, you should find that $l + 1.5j + 2c = 74$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying every step! I am starting to get a grasp of these word problem equations a little bit.